# QGIS: Hashed lined - advanced symbology and styling. 90*degree cornering and flexible widths

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function

TL;DR: How do i set up a symbology with hashed lines, that is not turning fluently around corners, but turns sharply at a 90 degree angle and stops overlapping. The corners are for all purposes close enough to 90 degreess to be hard coded as 90*s and the wanted width of hash lined marks fixed, so that the tappering can be done in fixed increments from the square corners.

[image: Current behavior:]

[image: Wanted behavior:]

I'm trying to create a "fantasy map" at home (thus also the rough MS Paint example made on the laptop) set in a historic theme. So i want to create a frame, where gray isn't achieved in the modern way with a mixture of ink, but rather like the old times where any print works was carved or stringed in copper with only one colour per template. Thus they acheived a psuedo gray behavior with lines of black close together. (And for you interest, any 1800's colour map was either individually hand painted after printing, or went through several print templates with different inks)

I've messed arround with the hashed line options in QGIS, a secific symbology i've never used. And whilst there's a lot of setting for calulating the placements of the hashed lines, i can't find one that can manipulate it as i wanted. And i more than just a novice in the SQL language and thus unprepared for the functions editor, sadly.

As mentioned in the TL;DR since it's a frame in the print layout (specifically a polygon rectangle is being used for my trial) and i have no other uses for this symbology, it will be totally acceptable if the solution is hardcoded for this 90 degree behavior, and the solution to the line lenght some coded table/index that i'd have to adjust to fit the end goal. My line of thinking is that i can edit the values myself, if i want a 2mm has lined, with 0,5 mm increments, to be whatever is nescessary at the corners to be pretty.